# Importing User Orders into Craft Commerce with Sprout Import?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-sproutimport

I'm attempting to migrate customer orders from a Wordpress website using Woocommerce to an out-of-the-box install of Craft Pro + Craft Commerce. I've been able to export the user orders as a CSV file, so I'm in the process of converting them to JSON and using [Sprout Import](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/import/docs/getting-started/introduction) to get them into Craft.

I'm using a slightly modified version of the example order template provided by the plugin. The purchaseableId values are set to products within the default Craft Commerce install (A New Toga and Romper for a Red Eye respectively.)

```
[
    {
        "@model": "Commerce_OrderModel",
        "attributes": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "billingAddressId": "6",
            "shippingAddressId": "7",
            "shippingMethod": "freeShipping",
            "paymentMethodId": 1,
            "customerId": 1,
            "orderStatusId": 1,
            "isCompleted": 1,
            "dateOrdered": "2017-07-02 01:08:38",
            "datePaid": "2017-07-02 01:09:38",
            "returnUrl": "/commerce/customer/order?number={number}",
            "cancelUrl": "/commerce/checkout/payment"
        },
        "content": {
            "title": "Test Order",
            "fields": []
        },
        "lineItems": [
            {
                "purchasableId": "5",
                "qty": "3",
                "options": []
            },
            {
                "purchasableId": "9",
                "qty": "1",
                "options": []
            }
        ],
        "payments": {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "number": "4929000000006",
            "month": "5",
            "year": "2017",
            "cvv": "123"
        }
    }
]
```

When I try to import the above JSON, Sprout Import seems to stall out indefinitely.

Could I get some insight on what I'm doing wrong? Additionally, could someone provide a simple example of importing orders into Craft Commerce with Sprout Import?